# Es coherente usar en una base de datos una tabla para registrar los precios y la fecha en que fueron establecidos?

Tags: base-de-datos

Hasta ahora en los diseños que hice, siempre he agregado el campo precio de un producto (o lo que fuere) como una propiedad de éste. 
pero a sabiendas de las evoluciones que pueden tener estos valores en el tiempo, me parece que se puede hacer la diferencia, más en aplicaciones que se usan en países donde los precios cambian tanto como argentina por ejemplo.
Aunque nunca lo vi.
Gracias, Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te interesa la evolución de los precios debes registrarla.

Eso significa disgregar el campo de la tabla PRODUCTO, y añadir una nueva tabla llamada PRECIOS, en plural por ser una atributo multivalorado.

Una clave única estará formada de todas sus tres columnas, (idProducto,fecha,precio), de las cuales idProducto es clave foránea. Cada uno de esos tres atributos debería ser NOT NULL, y la tripleta entera debería declararse como UNIQUE.

La combinación NOT NULL + UNIQUE podría ser una PRIMARY KEY.

Primary key es cuando alguien habla de ti, cuando se te referencia desde alguna parte externa.

Espero que sirva.